# Is it possible to have one checkbox toggle another checkbox On/Off?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I am new to google script and I have been trying to make it so when one checkbox is set to True, the other checkbox will be set to False, onEdit. Could anyone show me what that code would look like?

Answer (score 2):

## Toggling Checkboxes

Here's an onEdit function that will toggle the checkboxes in the same row to opposite states. Essentially, they behave like groups of radio buttons on each row.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var value=rg.getValue();
  var ss=e.source;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  if(name=='Sheet22' && (col==3 || col==1) && row>0 && row<16){//row>0 is not required unless you change the locations
    //Logger.log('Row: %s Col:%s',row,col);
    var hi=15;
    var lo=1
    var l=sh.getRange(lo,1,hi,1);
    var m=sh.getRange(lo,2,hi,1);
    var r=sh.getRange(lo,3,hi,1);
    var mA=m.getValues();//Anything can be in this array as I wont be setting values in that range
    switch(col){
      case 1://left
        lA=l.getValues();
        for(var i=0;i<lA.length;i++){
          mA[i][0]=lA[i][0]?false:true;
        }
        r.setValues(mA);
        break;
      case 3://right
        rA=r.getValues();
        for(var i=0;i<rA.length;i++){
          mA[i][0]=rA[i][0]?false:true;
        }
        l.setValues(mA);
        break;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Here's what the spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

[image]

1. [GS Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/)
2. [Javascript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)
3. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

I got to playing around with this and here's another way to do it with more columns:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var value=rg.getValue();
  var ss=e.source;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var col=rg.getColumn();
  var row=rg.getRow();
  var rows=sh.getLastRow();
  var cols=5;
  var shName='Sheet22';
  if(name==shName && col<=cols && row>1 && row<=rows){
    Logger.log(col);
    Logger.log(row);
    var cRg=sh.getRange(2,1,rows,cols);
    var cA=cRg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<cols;j++){
        if(row==i+2 && cA[i][col-1] && j!=col-1){//see comment below 
          cA[i][j]=false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  cRg.setValues(cA);
}
```

The comment for the selected line above is that if this is the selected row and if it is not the selected column and the selected column for this row is checked then uncheck this column.

And the spreadsheet looks something like this:

[image]

In this version you can have each row all unchecked but if you check one all the others are set to unchecked.  You can uncheck the checked one and then all will be unchecked for that row.  There are a lot of scenarios so you just have to figure out the logic that you wish to implement.

- [getValues() Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [setValues() Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Wow I really appreciate your thorough answer. This makes a lot more sense now, I was wondering down a wrong path. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. I’d appreciate it if you could check my answer.  Thanks.